# Connect to multiple DB's from different servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd

I have multiple DB's on different servers and I want to take some information from a table (for example User- this table is on all DB's). So I add all servers and DB's on a cursor and then I run this script:

```
BEGIN

fetch next from CursorData into @DBName,@DBServer

set @cmd=':Connect ' + @DBServer+ CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+ 'use ['+@DBName+'] select * from [UserAccount] where userid='''+@UserID+'''' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+  'GO'

  print @cmd

exec sp_executeSQL @cmd

END
```

and I have follow error:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

:Connect DBServer
use [DBName] select * from [UserAccount] where userid='myuserid'
GO

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Database 'DBName' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

For switching between server I used sqlcmd mode but I don't know if works when I put it a string and then execute string.

If, I execute this command in sqlcmd mode work:

```
:Connect DBServer
use [DBName] select * from [UserAccount] where userid='myuserid'
GO
```

If anybody know what I missed or know another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create [Linked Server objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff772782.aspx) for all your different servers, pull over all the relevant data onto your working server and then query the data from there.

Per the link above, you can do this in SSMS by expanding `Server Objects` in the Object Explorer, right clicking `Linked Servers` and then filling in the appropriate connection info.

If they are all SQL Server based, you can query them with `[Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]` notation and if not you will need to use `OPENQUERY`.

Comment: I must find a solution except Linked Server. DBA want to write a script or something similar to resolve this.

Comment: @SilviuS  What is wrong with linked servers?  Have you looked into using variables in your SQLCMD: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111339/user-shared-queries-dynamic-sql-vs-sqlcmd ?

Comment: For me is nothing wrong with this solution. I have a role that  cannot create Linked Server objects(I am not allowed) and this is why I try to find another solution

Comment: @SilviuS  Is your SQLCMD in the right syntax for being executed by `sp_executesql`?  The examples I can find online are in the format `N'''sqlcmd -E -S ' + @@servername + ' -w 1000 /Q "' + @query + '"'''` or similar, as it appears the `sp_executesql` does not execute in `CMD Mode`.